# Are performance bond and sanction the same thing?

Tags: international

I am translating a legal text into English. The original text (Persian) has footnoted "Zemanat Ejraii" which literally means performance bond as *sanction* but I doubt its correctness. Looking up both terms in legal dictionaries, I infer that performance bond is more appropriate in the context of providing guarantee for performing in accordance with some international agreement or treaty, but sanction is probably most suitable in case of punishing an infringement or breach. Part of the context says:

> Realization of sanctions in each legal system depends on creating two elements: the legal element i.e. measures predicted in law against violation of legal regulations and the executive authority superior to society powers that requires a power to ensure law enforcement across the whole society, being able to counter any rioting power and enforce predicted punishments (Bagherzadeh, 2002).

I assume *performance bond* should replace all occurrences of *sanction* in the context, but I am not sure this is the case due to my little background in law.

Answer (score 1):

**Performance Bond** Definition: [Source: Duhaime's Law Dictionary](http://www.duhaime.org/LegalDictionary/P/PerformanceBond.aspx)

> A contract wherein a third-party, in exchange for a fee, secures another's fulfillment of a contract or performance of a duty.

**Sanction** Definition: [Source: Law.com](http://dictionary.law.com/Default.aspx?selected=1880)

> n. 1) a financial penalty imposed by a judge on a party or attorney for violation of a court rule, for receiving a special waiver of a rule, or as a fine for contempt of court.

I think the text is fine as it is. Without substitution.

It would not make sense to me to substitute ***sanction*** with ***performance bond*** as I understand your question. My reading of the passage is that the ***realization of sanctions*** requires two elements. Not the realization of a performance bond.